# Error: Object 'X' not found - while deploying random forest model in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to deploy a random forest model (model.rds, that was already developed, stored in the same folder) in shiny. However, I ran into the error shown below.

```
Warning: Error in eval: object 'reports' not found
  133: eval
  132: eval
  131: model.frame.default
  129: predict.randomForest
  126: <reactive:datasetInput> [/Users/.../app.R#145]
  110: datasetInput
   97: renderTable [/Users/.../app.R#173]
   96: func
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$tabledata
    1: shiny::runApp
```

Other information, including ui.R (user interface), server.R (server) shown below

First, this is the information I have before getting into the ui.R.

```
# Import required libraries

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)
library(randomForest)
library(AER)
library(flexdashboard)

# Read the random forest built and saved from model.R

model <- readRDS("model.rds") #This is built in model.R and saved as model.rds, which is stored in the same folder
```

See the code incorporated in the user interface (ui.R)

```
######### User Interface #############
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  
  #Page header
  headerPanel('Prediction: Probability of Credit Card Approval'),
  
  #Input values
  sidebarPanel(
    HTML("<h5>Select Input Features</h5>"),
    
    selectInput("owner",
                label = "Owner",
                choices = list("yes" = "yes", "no" = "no"),
                selected = "yes"),
    selectInput("selfemp",
                label = "Selfemployed",
                choices = list("yes" = "yes", "no" = "no"),
                selected = "no"),
    
    sliderInput("reports", 
                label = "Derogatory_Reports",
                min = 0,
                max = 14,
                value = 3),
    sliderInput("age",
                label = "Age",
                min = 1,
                max = 84,
                value = 33),
    sliderInput("income",
                label = "Income",
                min = 0.2,
                max = 14,
                value = 3.5),
    sliderInput("share",
                label = "Share_of_CCard_Exp_to_Yrly_Inc",
                min = 0,
                max = 1,
                value = 0.10),
    sliderInput("expenditure",
                label = "Avg_Mthly_CCard_Expenditure",
                min = 0,
                max = 3100,
                value = 185),
    sliderInput("dependents",
                label = "No_of_Dependents",
                min = 0,
                max = 6,
                value = 2),
    sliderInput("months",
                label = "Months_Living_at_Current_Address",
                min = 0,
                max = 540,
                value = 56),
    sliderInput("majorcards",
                label = "No_of_Major_CCards_held",
                min = 0,
                max = 1,
                value = 0.8),
    sliderInput("active",
                label = "No_of_Active_Credit_Accounts",
                min = 0,
                max = 46,
                value = 7),
    
    actionButton("submitbutton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
    #submitButton("Submit")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    tags$label(h3('Status of Credit Card Application')),
    verbatimTextOutput('contents'),
    tableOutput('tabledata')#, # Prediction results table
  )
)
```

Information of the code in the server.R is shown below

```
######### Server #####################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Input data
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    
    df <- data.frame(
    Name = c("Owner",
             "Selfemployed",
             "Derogatory_Reports",
             "Age",
             "Income",
             "Share_of_CCard_Exp_to_Yrly_Inc",
             "Avg_Mthly_CCard_Expenditure",
             "No_of_Dependents",
             "Months_Living_at_Current_Address",
             "No_of_Major_CCards_held",
             "No_of_Active_Credit_Accounts"
             ),
    Value = as.character(c(input$owner,
                           input$selfemp,
                           input$reports,
                           input$age,
                           input$income,
                           input$share,
                           input$expenditure,
                           input$dependents,
                           input$months,
                           input$majorcards,
                           input$active
                           )),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  card <- 0
  
  
  df <- rbind(df, card)
  input <- transpose(df)
  write.table(input, "input.csv", sep = ",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  
  test <- read.csv(paste("input", ".csv", sep=""), header = TRUE)
  
  Output <- data.frame(Prediction = predict(model,test), round(predict(model, test, type = "prob"), 3))
  
  print(Output)
  })
  
  #my_plot <- reactive({
  #  gauge(datasetInput()$Yes, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', label = "Approval", gaugeSectors(
  #    success = c(80,100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)
  #  ))
  #})
  
  #datasetInput()
  #output$Scale <- renderGauge({
  #  my_plot()
  #})

# Probability Text Box
output$contents <- renderPrint({
  if (input$submitbutton>0) {
    isolate("Decision Made.")
  } else {
    return("Click SUBMIT After Selecting the Values of Features")
  }
})

# Prediction results table
output$tabledata <- renderTable({
  if (input$submitbutton>0) {
    isolate(datasetInput())
  }
})
}


######## Create the shiny app #########
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions. I have been trying other similar questions but did not work any solutions.

I was expecting to run the random forest model and give me a table showing the predictions of the dependent variable but instead the following error is shown in the app after selecting the features and clicking the submit button.

`Error: object 'X' not found`

Comment: I might be confused, but your title and the last sentence in your question say `object 'X' not found` yet (1) there is no `X` in your code, and (2) the error in your first code block says `object 'reports' not found`. Further, there is no `reports` object, just the named entry in `input$`, which should not be giving that error. If you're receiving an error because the data used to train your `model` in `"model.rds"` is built differently than the data you provide in `test`, then all bets are off.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To clarify, the 'X' in `object 'X' not found` represents generalization. That is, X could be `reports` or any other inputs. When running randomForest model, the names of the features used are exactly what were listed in Value data.frame in the server.R. That is, "owner,..., active" in the `input$owner,...., input$active`. In the user interface, these names are exactly same. Not sure about this error.